# how to get server data after fragment is created without freezing ui

Tags: android

I have two fragments and I have slide in, slide out transitions between fragments, after my fragment is loaded, I try to fetch data from server and load data into an array adapter, my problem is, I see my fragments freeze between transitions, I use execute to execute my asynctask in background, here is my code, DownloadJson extends to AsyncTask

```
public void onResume() {
    DownloadJson downloadJson = new DownloadJson();
    downloadJson.execute("http://somesite.com");    
}
```

How can I start fetching data after fragment is loaded without freezing between transitions, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use thread insted using asynctask.
asynctask still work in ui thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //download jason... after that

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //you can access to ui here when download is finished...
            });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: What about getting and reacting to the response ?.

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah code that i wrote is exactly do that you want, If I understand correctly...

Comment: This just will do something and ends, How should I return the value to the main UI thread ?

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah every things between public void run() { /*All code run in ui thread */ }, you can call function and it will run in UI, Of course when you call function, you can pass argument to  function...

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can't use any network activity on main UI Thread, you'll get a NetworkException. You can solve this by using new `Thread(new Runnable() {....});` , something like this :

```
DownloadJson downloadJson = new DownloadJson();
Thread t = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            downloadJson.execute("http://somesite.com");  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

//move on with the code, and get data from Thread.
t.start();
```

I'm casting into JSONObject for demo only, you need to set the right cast on your side.